# Can I backtest a hedging strategy in?

Tags: bots, pine-script, trading, tradingview-api

I have a strategy that starts with a future short position, then a spot positions opens afterwards, and its entry point is related to the futures position. Can I open both positions and decide when to close one with conditions applied on the other one?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a backtest script can test simultaneously more than 1 asset unfortunately
However, we can use other assets for internal calculations but ultimately, the backtest results can only be for 1 asset

Comment: Thanks for the answer! other than pinescript what solutions can I use to test my strategy?

Comment: if you want to only trade 1 ticker but needs the calculations from another ticker for your final signals, you can use the request.security() function to request the data for the other ticker
Documentation: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request{dot}security